# Populating a Telerik Grid using ViewModel (MVC3)

Tags: grid, telerik, viewmodel

Ok, this is a really newbie question but I am stumped.
I am trying to use a ViewModel to get my data from an entity object and populate the telerik mvc grid.

At this point I am a bit confused and need your help.

I understand the error message but I am not sure how I need to fix this since I am really new to MVC.

----ERROR----

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ProjectRepository.cs 23 20 MvcMyAPP

I have this viewmodel:

--VIEWMODEL--

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace mvcMyModel.ViewModels
{
    public class ProjectViewModel
    {
        public IQueryable<mvcMyAPP.Models.ProjectRepository> ProjectList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

--CONTROLLER--

```
namespace MvcMyAPP.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Home/
        ProjectRepository Repository = new ProjectRepository();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProjectViewModel objProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
            objProjectViewModel.ProjectList = Repository.GetProjects();
            return View(objProjectViewModel);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

----REPOSITORY (MODEL)-----

```
namespace mvcMyAPP.Models
{
    public class ProjectRepository
    {

        mvcMyAPP.Models.MYEntities MYDB = new MYEntities();
        //Fetching data from table

        public IQueryable<mvcMyAPP.ViewModels.ProjectViewModel> GetProjects()
        {
            var vProjects = (from tblProjects in MYDB.Projects
                                select tblProjects);
            return vProjects;
        }
    }
```

---GRID---

```
@{Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.ProjectList)
.Name(
"Grid") 
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Groupable()
.Render();
}
```

Comment: Ok, my entity class had a namespace almost identical to the namespace created by the project.
I had mvcMyAPP for controllers and models etc. The Entity classes had a namespace of MvcMyAPP. The capital M simply made the entity class unavailable and I did not notice. Once I accessed MvcMyAPP.T_PROJECT an set IQueryable<MvcMyAPP.T_PROJECT> as the return type, it worked. Weww!

Comment: You don't have to post a comment to provide more info. Just edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second return View() in the controller, but that isn't causing any problems.

You might try putting a cast on the return variable from your repository so it is returning the type specified in return:

```
 // return vProjects;

 // cast the return variable to return type
 return (IQueryable<mvcMyAPP.ViewModels.ProjectViewModel>)vProjects;
```

I highly recommend Microsoft site for learning MVC, they have a great starting point for learning MVC.

```
 http://www.asp.net/mvc
```